# Render view if payment successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, stripe-payments

quick question about handling payment. I want to re-direct to a particular view (or display links) on a successful payment within a rails app how would you guys go about handling such an action ?

Also please let me know the best way to go about this avoiding security breaches and also what payment solution you will use and why.

Comment: Use redirect_to on what ? is what i am asking. How do i get info on a successful payment back to my app in order to use a redirect_to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is attempting to handle some sort of payments the best one going at the moment and many will agree is Active Merchant. I have not used it personally but if you read from their site: [Active Merchant](http://activemerchant.org/) I am certain it will explain the core benefits. I can also back up the fact that Active Merchant is the best solution to use because ruby-toolbox also highlights from the following: [Ruby Toolbox - Payments](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Payments) that is the most used. However there are variety of solutions out there for what you want it just depends what exactly you want it to do and what you want it to handle. Also with regards to redirecting to a particular view on successful payment you would have a `create` action in your `OrderController` or `PaymentsController` that would do something like:

```
 def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order]) #Create new order based on the 'new' action and pass in order object.
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart) #Add the line_items from the cart to the @order.

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save #Begin to save order
        OrderMailerProcess.order_process(@order).deliver

        #OrderMailerProcess is called and passes in the order
        #and uses the .deliver function that sends the user the email.
        #The OrderMailerProcess is a mailer set in mailers directory. order_process
        #is the function that handles the mailer.

        Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) #If the order is saved destroy the current session of the cart.
        session[:cart_id] = nil #Cart_id now becomes nil

        format.html { redirect_to(root_url, :notice => #Format into ht
            'Thank you for your order you will recieve an email shortly.') }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
```

From the provided example above this create action is a snippet of how you may go about creating an order, and upon saving the order a mailer is triggered to that user detailing what they ordered. But the most relevant stuff to you is that inside the `format.html` block the `redirect_to(root_url, :notice....)` this means that upon creating the order the user is then redirected to the root of your application which in most e-commerce systems would be `home#index`. Should clear things up

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read up on active merchant. Sounds like just what i need.

Comment: If this answered your question don't forget to mark it complete :)